# Disabling firewall on a CentOS7 EC2 instance using a custom AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, firewalld

I built an AMI (RedHat Linux) using Amazon's EC2 Image Builder service. I created a EC2 instance using this AMI, and found that there are certain firewall rules set (ran the following command `iptables -nL`). Unfortunately, I was not able to find the configuration for setting these rules. Here are a couple of commands I ran to check for the configuration:

1. `systemctl status iptables` - iptables config is not located
2. `systemctl status firewalld` - returns a status of `inactive` for firewalld

I am not able to communicate with this instance from outside, though there is a public ip available. Any suggestions on how to disable these set rules? I tried disabling them using - `systemctl stop firewalld`, `systemctl disable firewalld`, but since the status of firewalld is inactive, the rules still existed.

Another approach I tried was creating a component in my AMI which flushes the rules in iptables:

- `iptables -F INPUT`
- `iptables -F FORWARD`
- `iptables -F OUTPUT`

The AMI was created successfully, but the rules still existed when I launched an instance. However, other components (in which I was installing some packages) worked well.

Any suggestions on how to disable the firewall?

Comment: Have you saved the rules, `iptables save`? By default iptables resets after reboot if not saved. So if your instances launch from ami, they may not be affected by your un-saved rules.

Comment: `iptables-restore` is required after a reboot/restart, right?

Comment: This [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/626521/centos-7-save-iptables-settings) has useful info about centos7 firewall.

Comment: Are you using subnets or is this the default VPC?  Did you add a SG to allow inbound traffic?

Comment: Also, check subnet route table to route traffice accordingly and VPC NACLs (default allows all traffic)

Comment: I'm using subnets. My instances were created successfully when I allowed all traffic (I had only certain ports open before; cleared the, from the AWS console). My question was really this - is there an ami-based approach to edit/remove these rules, instead of from the console?